# iOS 8 Share Extension Attachments - Xcode - Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, ios8-share-extension

I have added a Share Extension to my iOS app, and have created a custom UI using UIViewController, NOT the default SLComposeServiceViewController. The UI is working, but how do I refer to the files that were chosen to be shared? For instance, if I hit share on a photo, how do I refer to that photo, and convert it to NSData. I currently have this code, but when it runs, data never seems to be initialized. What am I doing wrong?

```
    //Runs when button is pressed
    inputItem = extensionContext!.inputItems.first as NSExtensionItem
    attachment = inputItem.attachments![0] as NSItemProvider
    attachment.loadItemForTypeIdentifier(kUTTypeJPEG as String,
        options: nil,
        completionHandler: {(content, error: NSError!) in
            let url = content as? NSURL
            if let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(url!) as NSData?{
                self.imageChosen = UIImage(data: data)!
                //Never runs
            }
            else {
                //Always runs
            }

    })
```

Also, how do I make the extension button disappear when the chosen attachment contains more than one file (photo or video), or is an invalid file type. Any answer is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does the `NSExtensionActivationRule` look like for this extension?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I prefer to share images and files:

```
//when the share button is pressed, default share phrase is added, cropped image of highscore is added

    var sharingItems = [AnyObject]()

    var shareButtonHighscore = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("highscore") as Int!

    sharingItems.append("I am sharing \(shareButtonHighscore)!")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.view.drawViewHierarchyInRect(view.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    sharingItems.append(image)

    let activityViewController = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: sharingItems, applicationActivities: nil)

    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = [UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,UIActivityTypePostToTencentWeibo,UIActivityTypePostToVimeo,UIActivityTypePrint,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypePostToWeibo]

    self.presentViewController(activityViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ah, this is for sharing within an app, I believe. What I need is a way so that when you press share on a photo or file in your photo library or Safari, it refers to the file and converts it into NSData. Thanks anyways, this can be helpful for future games I will make.